# Azure Analysis Services maximum allowable memory issue

Tags: azure, memory, business-intelligence, azure-analysis-services

I have an issue which I am encountering quite often lately. I am using Analysis services Standard tier ie. having 20GB of memory. However sometimes when I process the cube i get the following error:

> "Exception: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.OperationException: Failed to
>   save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'You have reached
>   the maximum allowable memory allocation for your tier. Consider
>   upgrading to a tier with more available memory. Technical Details:
>   RootActivityId: e024b2d1-ce22-4edd-9a21-68b6b288d7bb Date (UTC):
>   8/11/2017 11:48:20 AM '. at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Model.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   saveOptions) at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Model.SaveChanges(SaveFlags
>   saveFlags) at Submission#0.Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log) in
>   :line 59 Stack trace: at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Model.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   saveOptions) at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Model.SaveChanges(SaveFlags
>   saveFlags) at Submission#0.Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)  "

Basically the tabular uses the xVelocity in memory engine so all the data is in memory. So does this mean that the memory includes all the memory in the database and also all the memory required by the Calculated tables in the tabular model please? And if one uses partitions to process the model would it solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data from the model is all in memory. If you have only one partition that is already processed and you call process full on it, you will need double the memory. Partitioning the data and only loading new/changed partitions would avoid you needing double the memory.